# Read XML from String

Tags: asp.net, xml, visual-studio-2010, sql-server-2005

I have data in XML format. I stored it in varchar datatype column. I have retrieved it by using Linq to sql in visual studio 2010. I got xml format data in string variable. now i need read it as a Xml. I need to take value in particular node.

```
for example,
<Sale>
<LTV>150</LTV>
<CLTV>350</CLTV>
<DLTV>600</DLTV>
</sale>
```

I NEED TO TAKE CLTV value.

Answer (score 0):

try

```
    var xml = XElement.Parse("your xml");

//Gives you the value of the CLTV node
    xml.Descendants("CLTV").FirstOrDefault().Value;
```

To change the value

```
xml.Descendants("CLTV").FirstOrDefault().Value = "1";

//Save to disk
xml.Save({stream or file location});

//Get a string back
xml.ToString();
```

Descendants will give you a list of XElements that you can enumerate or by doing FirstOrDefault you will get the first one it finds or an empty Element.

Comment: See Update, However your question didnt state you wanted to update the value.

Answer (score 0):

This code should work for you:

```
using System.Xml;
...
string xmlStr = "<sale><LTV>150</LTV><CLTV>350</CLTV><DLTV>600</DLTV></sale>";
XmlDocument x = new XmlDocument();
x.LoadXml(xmlStr);
MessageBox.Show(x.GetElementsByTagName("CLTV")[0].InnerText);
```

Answer (score 0):

```
var value = XDocument.parse("YOUR_XML_STRING").Root.Element("ELEMENT_NAME").Value;
```